# blank screen (w/ audio) when playing H265 on Windows XP (VLC-ripped DVD)

Tags: windows-xp, vlc-media-player, dvd

Am using [portableapps.com version of VLC 3.04 for 32-bit Windows](https://portableapps.com/apps/music_video/vlc_portable)

I used VLC to rip a DVD (to show snippets for a class I'm teaching). By rip I mean I used VLC's "save stream to a file" feature.

I had to use my Windows XP machine to do this because that's the only machine I have with a DVD player.

When choosing options for VLC's "save stream to file" I had the option of using H264+mp3 but I decided to use H265+mp3, because I've never used it before and wanted to try it out.

It produced a `.mp4` file (as expected). But when I play the file in the same VLC I used to create it (and on Windows XP), I get a blank screen with audio.

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be welcome.

Comment: Have you tried using H264+MP3 to see if this also does the same thing?

Comment: @NetworkKingPin H264+MP3 worked just fine. But I'm still curious about why H265 isn't playing and hoping to find a config that'll make it play. This will also let me study the difference in compression size and quality between the 2 formats.

Comment: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=145534 try what this guy says and add it to your question if you want.